# Ntbtlog is contains one line only, is this normal

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have been reading [this article about manual rootkit removal](http://computersight.com/software/how-to-manually-remove-rootkit/). However, the `ntbtlog.txt` created in the `Windows` directory contains only one line and nothing else.

> Loaded driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\asyncmac.sys

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is a normal Windows system driver and the file path is correct, your boot log appears to be clean. It is possible the file has been infected by a rootkit, if you suspect it is run a [system file checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

> The process known as MS Remote Access serial network driver (asyncmac.sys) belongs to software Microsoft Windows Operating System by Microsoft

[Source of information](http://www.file.net/process/asyncmac.sys.html)

Comment: @noneam, so it was infected? If so, what was it infected with?